# What does this DNS entry do?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

```
Type - Host - Value - TTL

CNAME Record - www - www.my_domain.ai.herokudns.com - 30 min
```

I am using Namecheap DNS to host to Heroku which provided that CNAME entry above.

Does it assume that a host of www is actually www.my_domain.ai, that is the confusing part as www seems too general.

Answer (score 0):

CNAME designates that the record is the Canonical name for the server, essentially an alias which indicates that it is a webserver, hence the WWW portion of the name.

Comment: Can I assume that `www.my_domain.ai.herokudns.com` points to `www.my_domain.ai`

Answer (score -1):

in general all FQDN end up with "dot" at the end (root of the DNS). For normal usage the dot is not explicitly written. In dns zone record definition it is crucial. The record in the zone have to be related to the zone or it's subzone (there is exception like glue records etc.). In case you write just some text which is  not ending with dot it is handled like relative record to the zone it is a member. On the other side once you end up the record or value with the dot it mean that the record / value is not relative but absolute FQDN.

The records you are mentioning is part of the zone **my_domain.ai** that is the reason why simply **www** end up as **www.my_domain.ai**. In case of CNAME record it can be both relative or absolute value. In this case I guess you have forgot the dot at the end of the value so the value **www.my_domain.ai** pointing out of zone scope. In this  example it is pointing from the **my_domain.ai** to subdomain of **herokudns.com**.

Comment: I stopped at `FQDN` what is that?

Comment: Hmm, you have probably didn't even try to find out... ok Fully Qualified Domain Name - one of the basic terms related to DNS. This way it will take long time to understand it. Anyway good luck !

Comment: Sorry you were downvoted ... it was not me ... Can I assume that www.my_domain.ai.herokudns.com points to www.my_domain.ai

Comment: more precise is that www.my_domain.ai is pointing to www.my_domain.ai.heroku.com. You have mentioned that you have dns services there. Is there also some hosting for the web ?